# Yii2 allow access to inactive users

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

I need to allow access to some controllers and actions to users that are inactive.

Those users are not guests, they have been already signed up, but not have been yet activated (they have `User::STATUS_INACTIVE` status).

So what I need to do is to allow those users to fullfil their profiles, and only after that they should be activated from backend.

Can't find any clues how to achieve this.

Comment: You can create custom Authorization Component with behaviour and extend it to create the Controllers that need the permission check.

Checkout: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization

Comment: Do you want to allow inactive users to log in and limit where they can go after login? If that's true you should take a look at RBAC described in article the Harish ST posted. If you only want to send them some temporary link where they would fill in their profiles, then you can generate some random token. After that you can use access filter to check validity of token in url for that one action.